# Why is my promise chain still executing simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I want to make sure the database opens properly, then execute the get statement, then output it. But I am the following in the console where it's getting executed simultaneously. Thanks in advance!

Console log:

```
here1
here2
usergp is undefined
usergp in get is 10931
```

Desired output:

```
here1
usergp in get is 10931
here2
usergp is 10931
```

Code:

```
let selectGP = 'select gp from Money where userID = ? and guildID = ?';
    let userGP;
    let db;
    const openDB = new Promise(resolve => {
        db = new sqlite3.Database('./Toothless.db', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
            }
        });
        resolve();
    });
    x = openDB.then(() => {
        console.log('here1');
        db.get(selectGP, [interactionUserID, interactionGuildID], (err, row) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('in test > select GP');
            } else {
                userGP = row.gp;
                console.log('usergp in get is ' + userGP);
                return userGP;
            }
        });
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log('here2');
        console.log('usergp is '+ data);
        interaction.reply({
            content: 'you have ' + data
            , ephemeral: true
        });
        db.close();
    }).catch(() => {
        console.log('in catch');
    });
```

Comment: try using `async` and `await`.

Comment: what do you mean by simultaneously? it seems they're executed in the correct order

Comment: Right now I'm just working with data I know that exists first to get them working, before catching errors

Comment: @marvinIsSacul Won't help

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/427 https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572

Answer (score 1):

- you're not returning any value from the first step of the promise chain, thus breaking it, so `data` in the next step will always remain empty.
  does `db.get` return a promise? if so, you can return that (or declare the first step as an `async` function, and return the awaited value, i.e. `return await db.get(...)`. as comments mentioned - `async`/`await` is not the point here - it's just another way to express the nested asynchronous flow you're after)
  in any case, you should also omit the `db.get` callback, and move that logic to the `then` callback.
- it would be a good idea to throw any error from the database (after logging them or whatever), so it is caught by the later `catch()` step

if your aim is to change the order of execution, and `db.get` does not provide promises to work with, you can either wrap it with a promise yourself (tedious), or use a helper library for such flows, like [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async), that also has [utilities for such wrappings](http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#asyncify) (easy).

Comment: `db.get` fetches data from the database and the results is in the `row` variable. I am returning the variable `userGP` which is used in the next promise chain but the next promise chain is executed before my first return

Comment: The mention of `async`/`await` is a red herring. Asking whether `db.get` returns a promise is important, but the next sentence should be "*if it returns a promise, you need to `return` that, if it doesn't, then you need to promisify (wrap it in another `new Promise`) and `return` that.*"

Comment: @Bergi you are absolutely correct, i have already updated it during my editing iterations... it was an answer in a rush! thanx for noticing

Comment: @ToothlessLL, the flow is understood. i updated my answer to include more info. you can try and research further to implement it with the methods offered above